How to style QTabWidget with PySide6
How can I maximize the space taken up by children of QTabWidget using PySide6?
IOW, I don't want the padding the QTabWidget container takes up before drawing the child inside of it.
In the image you can see there is a lighter shade of gray from the background of the tab widget parent.  I want to remove this lighter gray and have the child expand to fill that space.
And as a bonus I want the tab bar showing the names of the tab to be on top of the QTabWidget draw area, not halfway between the tab area and parent area.


Is that QTabWidget added to a layout, or is it a top level window? In the first case, just use setContentsMargins() with 0 margins, otherwise try with the tab widget's setContentsMargins(), but it's possible that the mac style just hardcodes that for OS look consistency. In any case, just look at the QSS reference docs and related examples.

Just be aware about this: "With complex widgets [...] if one property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well." If you fail to do so, Qt will revert to the fallback (and ugly) mix of QCommonStyle/QWindowsStyle. This means that it's almost impossible to do what you want while keeping the exact look derived from the OS style: you may get similar results, but they may be inconsistent in other OS or user configurations (including custom user colors).

@musicamante I dont care about it looking like OS styles.

@musicamante QTabWidget is added to a layout.  I extended it into my own widget, but when I setContentsMargin(0,0,0,0) it doesn't seem to change anything.

Sorry, is the issue the margin around the tabwidget or within it? In the second case, you need to call setContentsMargins() on those contents. If you did, please provide a [mre] as it may depend on the plot you're showing there, which we don't know what is. About the styling, then just follow the docs and examples linked above.

@musicamante ideally both inside and outside margins should be removed.
